# Can you call checkValidity() on a <form> element?

Tags: javascript, html, constraint-validation-api

I was looking through the Constraint Validation API and found some example code online that seemed to call `checkValidity()` on `<form>` elements:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
  var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

But I tried to do this myself and it didn't work. I couldn't find any reference to this being possible anywhere else either. As far as I figured, it can't be called on `<form>`. Could someone help me out?

Comment: of course you can, I did it a lot ... https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp

Comment: If I understand well, you can use `checkValidity()` on some `input` element but not on `form`... : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp ... There is browser support list : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity

Comment: @johnSmith that's calling it on `<input>` right? I was asking about `<form>`. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: @edddd dude just use it on form element it works i dont have a feeling that you tried anything

Comment: it will return true if all of its input-elements' constraints are met.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `submit` , but if you are using `input` there is no `submit` event for it. You can use `input` or `paste` event handler for input

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
  var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
    form.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }, false);
  });
}, false);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='email' class='needs-validation'>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are many ways to dot this.
It seems like you have written a self-invoking JS function.
In the other simple way, you can simply write a onsubmit event attribute in  tag and write the function name.

e.g.

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkValidity()">
        //...rest stuff
</form>
```

Based on the returned result from the function, whether true or false depending on the conditions the form will get submitted or stop submission respectively.